# My app is not working after proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I'm new to proguard, and developing android app, after building with default android proguard config file(from sdk), nothing works, my assumption is related to code that finds resources on R file in runtime(yes ugly scanning file and search for resource id's).
I couldn't understand from proguard documentation how to prevent a file from being proccessed by progurad.

I think best way to learn why my app is failing is make proguard do nothing for start and then make it shrink specific stuff one by one.

So what I wanna know is how can I tell proguard to keep all my classes (even the unreachable code)(Is this even possible?).

and afterwards(hopfully my app wil work) telling him to shrink and obfuscate specific classes.

The error I get is file not found exception when trying yo load dynamically the R$id file.

Comment: Please describe the error you encounter at runtime or compilation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your  `proguard.cfg`, you can force Proguard to keep certain classes:

```
-keep class com.myapp.SomeClass { *; }
```

or even an entire package:

```
-keep class com.myapp.** { *; }
```

You will certainly have to do this for classes that are only referenced from an XML file.

Comment: Thanks but this is not enough, I need to keep file names also, I need all R files to stay as they are with their names.

Comment: Keeping entire package makes using proguard pointless since it won't obfuscate your app anymore